# What HTML tag is most appropriate for display in a Grid or Table? (with specific needs)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to build a CSS-based table that will be populated with information coming from a database.

What is the most appropriate tag to use for this structured data?  I originally considered ul since each row is an unordered list of data... but then I uncovered some difficulties making it into a grid using CSS.

I'm now looking at DIV (inline?) and Span.  There may be others.  What tag would be considered the industry standard way of displaying a CSS based grid?

Although I'm interested in learning what's most appropriate one from a DOM-Theory perspective, ultimately I want clean code that is consistent among browsers...  This may weed out the ul tag entirely.

What do the experts think?

**Update**

So it seems that everyone is recommending that I use a table for (duh) tabular data.  The only reason I don't feel silly for asking this question is because my ASP.net grid vendor is having issues with a dynamically resizing grid... and allowing for the columns to be resized on the client.

The vendor claims that the reason columns are having issues with a resize is because of tables.  They will be moving to a DIV based layout to fix the issue.  I'll post a reference link shortly...

Search for the word "Based" and you will see the posting from a MVP who mentions the internal changes:
http://stagev5.componentart.com/community/forums/t/60782.aspx

**Update 2:**

Perhaps a large non-table based grid will also render faster.

You might say I need a lot of scalibility (for a large rowset) and the ability to resize the panes.  Very similar to how Outlook currently looks/operates:

[image]

Summary of needs:
I'm looking for a Table approach that allows for:

- Fast Rendering
- Large Datasets
- Rich formatting
- The ability to resize outer container/div
- When changing the width/height of outer container, the columns will keep the width property or grow, as defined in HTML

Comment: Do you have a comp/preview of it? It would really help seeing what it actually *contains*

Comment: Sometimes, its neither blasphemous nor sinful to use tables.

Comment: @meder The columns will contain graphical elements (graphs, images, etc).  If you look at the layout of Outlook's inbox where there is one row occupying 2 lines.... I'll add a sample image shortly.

Comment: @meder I didn't add a screenshot from my application, but the url will be eventvwr.com  ... based on that you can imagine the content I'll be adding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's a grid of data, it should be a `<table>`. It's fair enough to avoid using tables for layout, but if you have tabular data then that's exactly what tables are for.

Comment: Quite rite. I think most people get the impression there's a blind polarize almost like a religious war over the element's usage as if it were <blink>.

Comment: Aren't there issues with resizing the table as a whole, and adjusting (or not adjusting) column width as the table expands/shrinks? ... what about rendering speed? ...dealing with many records on the backend?

Comment: @MakerOfThings7: No more so than any other method. You can check it yourself in your browser of choice, but given that's exactly what the element is for rendering speed with many records is almost certainly going to be as fast, if not faster, than a div/span and CSS alternative.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a tabular or grid information display, then use the `table` element. It's there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to build a CSS-based **table** 
>   ...
>   What is the most appropriate tag

sometimes `<table>` is ok :), you don't have to be a 'cool kid' and do everything with `<div>`

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to display **tabular data** (i.e. it comes from a table, such as in a database), use the `<table>` element.  A `<div>` element can be useful if you plan on doing a lot of heavy formatting on each distinct value in each row from the database table, but if the way you're presenting data is more less in line with data reporting, a `<table>` will be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you.. yes, I will be doing heavy formatting on the data.  I posted a sample image after you left this comment.

Comment: @Maker in this case, you might consider using a heavily formatted `<div>` element.  For a very simple example, look at how StackOverflow arranges it's vote-up/vote-count/vote-down pieces into a single `<div class="vote">` element.

Comment: +1 layout and styling are both accounted for.  This is the most even-handed answer yet.  Thanks Ben!

Answer (score 1):

If your grid represents a list of items, then `<ul>` is appropriate.  You can get around your CSS woes by unstyling the ul/li and then using the child elements to dictate style:

```
ul, ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

ul a {
    float: left;
    background: red;

    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

The above display is controlled by the nested `<a>`, [as you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/hLURe/).

Comment: Neat approach! I'll be using this for one of my other projects +1 ... especially since you know the magic to make it actually render right

Comment: I wouldn't call this tabular though. It's actually a tile based display.

Comment: @poke me neither. I put it up to show OP how you could take the ul and li out of play if you were styling a list of items.

Comment: In case your interested, I used a similar approach here for a non grid/tile layout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469481/if-i-use-getelementbyid-to-alter-a-css-style-of-a-single-object-how-do-i-alter

Answer (score 1):

This might also interest you: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Scroll down through it to the `display: table` section.  Came across this the other day, this question reminded me of it.

If you absolutely HAVE to use CSS, give that a try. But, as other have said, use `<table></table>` if it's tabular data. If it's a straight-up list, then you can do it with `ul`, but it becomes more effort than it's worth.

EDIT: It should be noted that that example is using `div`s for the cells' CSS to be applied to.

Comment: I'm using IE8 on XP and the render of the Table doesn't look anything like the image reference sample (Firefox).  Perhaps the compatibility chart at the top needs updating or to list exceptions

Comment: @MakerOfThings7 Outta curiousity, was it running in compatibility mode, or full IE8 rendering mode?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a div tag, which you are then able to add additional styling to with far greater ease than an unordered list.

Comment: I would tend to agree, but the user has expressed an interest in the Div, which is rendered faster than a table by the browser.  I guess no one cares about performance?

Comment: "table format" - divs can be used to acheive a table layout. And nobody said anything about tabular data not being best displayed in a table layout. This answer just suggests a different way of implementing a table layout using divs instead on the table tag.