# If I use "getElementById" to alter a CSS style of a single object, how do I alter all elements that inherit the style?

Tags: jquery, css, dhtml, getelementbyid

All the examples I've seen use "getElementById" to get the single element, and then change that style for that singular element.

I'm in the situation where I need to modify all the matching elements on the page with a style.  I need to change the font size, height, and width.  How do I do this, and is jQuery required or optional?  The reason I ask is because this site doesn't use jQuery and I'd rather not download the entire library just to accomplish this one thing.

**Update**
As an example, suppose I have several elements on the page with this style:

```
.outerContact
{
    border: 0px;
    margin: 7px;    
    float: left;
   padding: 0px; 
 background: url(/TLSADMIN/UserControls/contactsgrid/trans-shadow.png) no-repeat bottom right; /* Most major browsers other than IE supports transparent shadow. Newer release of IE should be able to support that. */        
}
.contactLarge{
    height: 163px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:small;
    margin: -5px 5px 5px -5px; /* Offset the image by certain pixels to reveal the shadow, as the shadows are 6 pixels wide, offset it by that amount to get a perfect shadow */

  /* Most major browsers other than IE supports transparent shadow. Newer release of IE should be able to support that. */     
     background-image: url('/TLSADMIN/UserControls/contactsgrid/OutlookContactGradient.png') ;
     background-repeat:repeat-x;
      background-position: bottom;
padding: 0px; /* Increasing this gives a white border around the image */ 
background-color: #f2f6f9; /* Background color of the border created by the padding */
border: 1px solid #cecece; /* A 1 pixel greyish border is applied to the white border created by the padding */ 
display: block; /* IE won't do well without this */ 
position: relative; /* Make the shadow's position relative to its image */ 

}
```

And then assume I have a JavaScript function that will proportionally resize the elements above according to a slider bar.  The slider bar I'm using is available from a 3rd party here: 
http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/slider/features/custom_Scrollbar/WebForm1.aspx

That slider will then pass a number that I'll use to determine how much to zoom in/out:

```
function ResizeWindowAccordingToScrollBar(PercentChange)
{
 //Locate elements
 //Resize fonts, borders, all styles to zoom in/ zoom out.

}
```

How do you recommend I handle the "PercentChange" value?  I may swap out the CSS style for each matching element using a switch statment, but that may not be as smooth as other options could be.

**UPDATE2**

Also, if someone wants to look at my code, a self contained sample is here:
http://www.perfmon.com/download/StackOverflow_ContactsGrid.zip

If you download the ComponentArt Controls, feel free to uncomment the scrollbar code.

My goal is to directly emulate the zoom feature available in Outlook 2007

[image]

Comment: One approach would be to change the CSS class itself, but that is said to be cumbersome. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-class-itself-from-javascript

Comment: "I need to modify all the objects on the page with a style." please elaborate; do you mean "I need to modify all the objects on the page, adding/removing/changing a style" or "I need to modify all the objects on the page which have a particular style attribute."?

Comment: Do you by "all objects" really mean every element on the page?

Comment: @All - I just included more detail as requested

Comment: @Pekka - No, I only want to modify the objects with these styles.  There are other objects on the page that don't get modified

Comment: I'm deleting my answer below because I think 99% of this question is a misunderstanding of how CSS works or which particular properties and rules would achieve the effect you desire. The question you originally asked is different than what you have now.

Comment: @Richard JL LeGuen : I need to resize the elements... I suppose that means "I need to modify all the objects on a page (with a style attribute) and change it's style"

Comment: @Jesse Dhillon I apologize for my poor wording of the question... I don't want to cause confusion.  How do you recommend I phrase it?

Comment: @MakerOfThings7 - Your CSS code snippet above does not help us understand which elements you will need to re-size and which elements you don't want to re-size. I agree with @Jesse Dhillon; I suspect you might be a little confused... are you trying to resize `outerContact` elements? `contactLarge` elements?
 other elements?

Comment: @All - I uploaded a self-contained code sample, and an image demonstrating what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's say you have some HTML like this...

```
<div>
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <p>This is an example</p>
    <p>
        Some of this content can be re-sized.
    </p>
    <img src="lenna.jpg" class="iconic" alt="a petty lady" />
</div>
```

You need some of these elements to be zoomable/re-sizable. First, you need to identify those elements using [element identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2); either the `id` attribute or the `class` attribute.

The difference between the two is an `id` attribute has to be unique; since we need several items to be identified as zoomable, we'll use a `class` attribute instead. We'll use an appropriate, self-evident value, like `zoomable`.

```
<div>
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <p>This is an example</p>
<div>
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <p>This is an example</p>
    <p class="zoomable">
        Some of this content can be re-sized.
    </p>
    <img src="lenna.jpg" class="zoomable iconic" alt="a petty lady" />
</div>
</div>
```

Note that the `<img>` element already had a `class` attribute, but we can assign that element to multiple classes, according the to [w3c recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-class):

> This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.

So we've figured out the markup. Now for the JavaScript.

Once we've done that, you can use the `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` function to get references to all those `zoomable` elements:

```
var zoomables = document.getElementByClassName('zoomable');
for(var i=0; i<zoomables.length; i++) {
    zoomables[i].style.height = '100px';
    zoomables[i].style.width = '100px';
    zoomables[i].style.fontSize = '20px';
}
```

... but it's not supported in Internet Explorer, so you'll have to use [Object Detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) to determine if you need to define it instead:

```
if(!document.getElementsByClassName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className) { // this is the simplest, plainest, lowest-invested-time-and-effort
                                                            // version of getElementsByClassName  one can write...
        // you should probably sanitize that className input parameter a bit...
        var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for(var i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) {
            if(/\bclassName\b/.test(allElements[i].className)) {
                allElements[i].style.border = "2px solid red";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't completely solve your problem, but it should set you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for the IE and non-IE examples. It's very clear and I learned quite a bit, thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

If you google getelementbyclassname that might help you. Similar idea to getelementbyid but gets them by classname you can them modify their styles as you see fit.

Comment: this link might help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: It's not supported by IE, but you can check to see if the function exists, and if not use a custom one that just goes through all the elements and gets only ones with the class specified.  Although it would be easier to just use a JS framework.

Comment: There is a function someone else has written that is supported by ie:http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to create the class that you need in your CSS file and change it with jQuery.

```
.class1{background-color:#ff0000;}
.class2{background-color:#0000ff;}
```

And in jQuery :

```
$("#element").click(function(){
    $(".class1").removeClass("class1").addClass("class2");
});
```

This way, you do not need to do anything "weird" and complicated to get the result that you need.

Comment: Since I'm doing this to adjust the size of the elements... this is a possible approach... but it doesn't allow me to alter the class with a fractional number for say the width, height, or font size of the data I'm displaying